# Remove Duplicate Slashes and Backslashes in URL via .htaccess or PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to remove completely ALL slashes or backslashes at the end of the URL.

`http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\`

via .htaccess or PHP.

The following .htaccess rule do NOT work:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)[/\]+$ $1 [L,R=301]`

```
#### mod_rewrite in use
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
```

Please provide alternate solution.

Comment: How is this URL generated? By you or externally?

Comment: This is a testing tool. ALL url's are generated externally.

Comment: It doesn't work because the slashes are part of the query string. ["When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query string to the target URI"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd). See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for how to modify the query string using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\\"));
```

If there will be no \ appear earlier

---

**EDIT:**
The full code to test:

```
<?php
$string = "http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\\"));
echo($string);
?>
```

Comment: Well, the following code generates blank page: <?

$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\"));

?>

Comment: You had to change `$string` to the url. And if you want to see something you had to use `echo($string);` or `print $string;`.

Comment: As I have stated the entire code returns blank page:  <?php
$string = "http://www.mp7.org/?site=69.com\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\"));
echo($string);
?>

Comment: I found the problem \\ = \ because \ is the escape character you have 13 \ in the url if you want to escape al this caracters you had to test it with 26 \ see the edit

Comment: 13 \ gives a error because the last caracter escapes the ". Whats results that there will be missing a "

Comment: [Click here to see the code working](http://ideone.com/RdatVR)

Comment: I want ALL slashes or backslashes at the end of the URL to be removed, NO matter of the url or the number of the slashes/backslashes. If you have an idea how to process please insert the code here. Thanks